# How to login using Azure AD users in Windows virtual machine

Tags: azure, rdp

I have a Windows virtual machine in Azure and i would like to login via remote desktop RDP using Azure AD users.
I have read the ***Microsoft guide*** but maybe i need some more step to do.
While created the virtual machine i have activated the option "Login with azure AD".
Also, i have a user group with the users that will login in the VM by RDP.
Then, in the resourse group that contains all the resourses created with the VM (the VM, Virtual Network, Network interface, etc.), i've assigned the rol of "Virtual machine user login" to the user group.
Is this enough, or do i need to do something else??
I can login with the administrator user that i created with the VM.
I am using a PC with Windows 10 Home, version 22H2.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

To login using Azure AD users in Windows virtual machine check the below:

Created virtual machine activated the option ***"Login with azure AD"*** like below:

[image]

Try to assign role assignment **`Virtual Machine User Login`** and **`Virtual Machine Administrator Login`** to the user like below:

[image]

Download the RDP file in virtual machine:

[image]

Now, open the RDP file in notepad edit your RDP downloaded file including:

```
enablecredsspsupport:i:0
authentication level:i:2
```

[image]

Now try to login with **`AzureAd\UPN`** with user, it connected successfully like below:

[image]

if still the issue persists, login with your vm remote desktop in task bar type *allows remote connection to this computer* -> in system properties -> uncheck the box like below:

[image]

And in virtual machine -> Run command -> `DisableNLA` and Run script like below:

[image]